# SR Flip Flop not working

Tags: flipflop

Disclosure: I’m using the iCircuit app to model the question below

When I manually construct (in iCircuit, bottom half of image)the synchronous SR flip flop it works as expected. My expectation is that when holding clock HIGH, pressing the S button should illuminate the LED (and stay on) until the R input button is pressed.

When I insert what should be an equivalent IC (labeled SR flip flop in iCircuit, top half of image) I cannot cause the output Q to change state, no matter how I push those buttons or rewire it. I attached the image as I would expect it to work. Any advice? I am strictly attempting to learn, there is no project in mind.

[image]

Comment: When the buttons are not pressed the associated inputs will be floating and have undefined logic levels. You need to add pullup resistors between the switches and the gates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit above is a SR Flip-flop. The circuit below is a SR Latch.

They are not equivalent.

The triangle in the SR Flip-flop means it requires a clock edge (most likely rising) to operate, it does not work with only a static level at the clock terminal.

The SR Latch just has an enable input so it requires only a correct level to be enabled, no edge is necessary.

Comment: That was it, thank you. If I trigger the s or r pins whilst a clock signal comes in it works. Thank you for turning me towards the rising edge factor.